# I need a freehand /transform /skew/perspective tool for android

Tags: android, photography

My Samsung 9 actually came with a built-in one it was fabulous. You could pinch it and skew.... wasn't just vertical and horizontal perspective, you could actually do whatever you wanted to transform this then after the pie update it just went to vertical and horizontal perspective. I've tried Snapseed Lightroom and all these other things and you can mess with the perspective of what I need to do is to be able to have one picture and insert another picture on top of that and be able to change the perspective of the inserted picture. Lightroom and Snapseed don't do that. Any help? It has to be Android[image]

I tried to add a picture of what I need to do you can look on his canvas and see that I fit Royal trucks in there and I need to do that on a variation of different things. The Royal Trux picture used to be just a flat Square so that's what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Please add example before/after pictures, for each of the transformations you want. Thanks!

Comment: I added picture 